# Calling angular 4 router with Multiple parameters from C#

Tags: c#, angular, webapi2

I want to call router with multiple parameters using C#.Here is i am making url

```
 var _email = UtilityConverter.Encrypt(Email);
            var _userId = UtilityConverter.Encrypt(Convert.ToString(UserId));

            // this.router.navigate(['search', { term: term}]);

            var _subject = "Email Verification";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<html>");
            sb.Append("<body>");
            sb.Append("<p>Dear ,</p>");
            sb.Append("<p>Please click the below link to verify your email.</p><br>");
            sb.Append("<a href='http://localhost:4200/Emailverification/" + _email + "/" + _userId + "'>click here</a>");
            sb.Append("<p>Sincerely,<br>-Offey</br></p>");
            sb.Append("</body>");
            sb.Append("</html>");
            return MailUtilityHelper.SendMail(Email, _subject, sb.ToString());
```

My Email and userid is encrypted which cause the issue.

here is my router with multiple parameter

```
 {path:'Emailverification/:email/:userid', component:EmailVerficationComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardComponent]},
```

any help will be highly appreciated. gives me following error in console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are passing only one parameter to you'r router which is Emailverification/**something**

in you'r case you have to fill both the parameters to the url. 
If you want to make route parameters nullable you should declare another route with one parameter and another one with no parameter which should be

```
 {path:'Emailverification', component:EmailVerficationComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardComponent]},
 {path:'Emailverification/:userid', component:EmailVerficationComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardComponent]},
 {path:'Emailverification/:email', component:EmailVerficationComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardComponent]},
```

or you can catch error in you'r component:EmailVerficationComponent component.

Comment: http://localhost:4200/Emailverification/0tG4yjBd9CQMBoFtia0JmFjxPR3iaZjW5zpuE7NE7lU=/yww4Q9JSiKPyyVZ89sYMeA== 
this is my url which gives me following error

Comment: accourdin to the photo which you have uploaded you'r url has just one parameter , in you'r url ther is just one **/** ( slash)

Comment: yes it is but i am passing both of them and i am sure about it

Comment: aha , its because of **=** character , angular could not underestand **=** in its route url

Comment: I think the best way is to remove special characters in your backend and send the clean url to the client.

Comment: But i want to encrypt my email and userid

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt your email and userid by using some other encryption method. I will provide you encryption and decryption method without special characters. Which will solve your problem.

```
       public static string Encrypt(string stringvalue, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        Byte[] stringBytes = encoding.GetBytes(stringvalue);
        StringBuilder sbBytes = new StringBuilder(stringBytes.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in stringBytes)
        {
            sbBytes.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
        }
        return sbBytes.ToString();
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string hexvalue, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        int CharsLength = hexvalue.Length;
        byte[] bytesarray = new byte[CharsLength / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < CharsLength; i += 2)
        {
            bytesarray[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexvalue.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return encoding.GetString(bytesarray);
    }
```

Hope this helps you though it is not optimize solution but it may help you go through your problem.